# Setting typeface of unclicked tabs issue

Tags: android

In the `onTabChangeListener` of a `TabHost` I tried to make unclicked tabs to have a normal typeface :

```
@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    View tab = mTabHost.getCurrentTabView();
    TextView tabTitle = (TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.tabLabel);
    tabTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    View unclickedOnglet = null;
    if (mTabHost.getCurrentTab() == 1)
       unclickedOnglet = mTabHost.getChildAt(0);
    else
       unclickedOnglet = mTabHost.getChildAt(1);
    TextView unclickedOngletTitle = (TextView) unclickedOnglet.findViewById(R.id.tabLabel);
    unclickedOngletTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
}
```

It works on the first try : when I click the second tab then the first tab has a normal typeface. But when I click the first tab then the app crash ! So what is wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is like below

```
 View LastSelectedview=null;

 mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabName) {

            View tab = mTabHost.getCurrentTabView();
            Your all code here...

            clearSelection();
            LastSelectedview=tab;

        }
    });
```

and create `clearSelection()` method

```
private void clearSelection() {
    if(LastSelectedview!=null){
        TextView title2 = (TextView) LastSelectedview.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title2.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    }                           
}
```

Comment: it does not work ! every tabs become normal typeface !

Comment: @pheromix Actually i dont understand your question. what you want to do actually?

Comment: I want clicked tab to be bold , and unclicked tab to be normal.

Comment: @pheromix Now try another way as per my new answer.